# Can I bind custom props handler to every basic React html tag?

Tags: html, reactjs

What I want to do is something like below code.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arguments: {
        key: "value",
      },
    };
  }

  render(){
    const {arguments} = this.state;
    return (
      <div myCustomProps={arguments}>
        /*child DOM*/
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/*Custom handler implemented somewhere. */
function handler(argv = {}, otherProps){
  /*something special code.*/
}
```

I want to bind my own handler to basic html DOM like `<div/>`, `<h1/>`. But the problem is I do not know whether this concept can be implemented or not.

So I have thought alternative way to implement above, that is, makes kind of **Wrapper** like

```
<Wrapper myCustomProps={argument}>
  <div>
    /*child DOM*/
  </div>
</Wrapper>
```

and implement handler at **Wrapper** class. However this is quite annoying when there are many basic html DOM. (Code becomes difficult to understand.)

```
/*Annoying case*/
<Wrapper myCustomProps={argv1}>
  <div>
    <Wrapper myCustomProps={argv2}>
      <h1>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </h1>
    </Wrapper>
    <Wrapper myCustomProps={argv2}>
      <p>
        I am a SLAVE to
        <Wrapper myCustomProps={argv3}>
          <span>
            Wrapper.
          </span>
        </Wrapper>
      </p>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
</Wrapper>
```

Can I implement above concept?

Comment: I am wondering for what purpose do you want to have a handler for every HTML tag? I think this way may not be a good approach to reach your target. Can you share your problem behind this idea?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen Thank you for comment. I want to make more 'programming-linguistic' style(CSS) handler, and to do so, not just put **es3 style object** on style props, but **es5 style object** should be passed and handle this using my custom handler.

Comment: I am not quite clearly understand your idea. But have you tried https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen Thanks! usage of [github.com/gajus/react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) is what I exactly want.

Comment: @FiriceNguyen sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-css-module](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) will fit to your requirements